# How to check special characters with Regular Expressions?

Tags: javascript

In javascript I check for some characters but I want to allow underscores and slashes but I don't know how.

```
    alias: /^[a-z-Z0-9]{2,35}$/
```

How to put / and _ so it has not special meaning to Regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` has no special meaning at all in Regex.

And if a character has special meaning, you can use `\` to "despecialize" it.

```
alias: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\/]{2,35}/
```

(BTW, you can use `\w` which means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, i.e. `/^[\w\/]{2,35}/`. The `\` in `\w` turns a normal character `w` to have a special meaning.)

(Edit: Inside the `[…]` the `/` will not be recognized as a delimiter so it is safe to use `/^[\w/]{2,35}/`. Thanks Andy E for showing this.)

Comment: You don't actually need to escape the `/` inside square brackets

Comment: Like this then = alias: /^[/w/d\/_]{2,35}$/

Comment: @Andy: You need to escape it because the delimiter is `/`.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  `/test[/]/i` is a perfectly valid regular expression in JavaScript.